# Drupal 6 - How to fix combination Dutch domain - English URI

Tags: hyperlink, drupal-6, multilingual

In Google Webmaster Tools I have 60 non-existing combinations of my Dutch domain and the English original blog. Example:

http://website.nl/english-blog

The from English to Dutch translated blog exists.

This problem leads to a degraded customer satisfaction, as Drupal reports the web-page not to be found. What can I do to help Drupal find the correct translation, given the domain language.

I have checked the Global Redirect property to correct this, and automatically replace the English link with the Dutch link. To no avail.

I tried to correct it in Path redirect, but also to no avail. It is not allowed, because the module interprets it as the redirection of an alias, and advises the alias to be corrected. This does not work, because then the English web-page cannot be found.

My questions:

```
How do I fix this?
Why did I get it in the 1st place?
```

Thanks for any comment or suggestion.

Drupal up to date; Enabled modules: Global Redirect, Pathauto, Path Redirect.